# Golang xml doesn't unmarshal

Tags: xml, go, unmarshalling

Im trying to unmarshal the following code that has the go playground at the bottom. The data.DocumentType always returns 0 and should return the inner xml 4. Can someone tell me why this doesnt work?

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"

)

type doc struct {
    XMLName       xml.Name `xml:"ownershipDocument"`
    SchemaVersion string   `xml:",innerxml"`
    DocumentType  int      `xml:",innerxml"`
}

func main() {
    var Data doc
    xml.Unmarshal([]byte(VV), &Data)
    fmt.Println(Data.DocumentType)

}

const VV = `<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ownershipDocument>

    <schemaVersion>X0306</schemaVersion>

    <documentType>4</documentType>

    <periodOfReport>2015-11-18</periodOfReport>

    <issuer>
        <issuerCik>0000820081</issuerCik>
        <issuerName>CAMBREX CORP</issuerName>
        <issuerTradingSymbol>CBM</issuerTradingSymbol>
    </issuer>

    <reportingOwner>
        <reportingOwnerId>
            <rptOwnerCik>0001227832</rptOwnerCik>
            <rptOwnerName>KORB WILLIAM B</rptOwnerName>
        </reportingOwnerId>
        <reportingOwnerAddress>
            <rptOwnerStreet1>1 MEADOWLANDS PLAZA</rptOwnerStreet1>
            <rptOwnerStreet2></rptOwnerStreet2>
            <rptOwnerCity>EAST RUTHERFORD</rptOwnerCity>
            <rptOwnerState>NJ</rptOwnerState>
            <rptOwnerZipCode>07073</rptOwnerZipCode>
            <rptOwnerStateDescription></rptOwnerStateDescription>
        </reportingOwnerAddress>
        <reportingOwnerRelationship>
            <isDirector>1</isDirector>
            <isOfficer>0</isOfficer>
            <isTenPercentOwner>0</isTenPercentOwner>
            <isOther>0</isOther>
        </reportingOwnerRelationship>
    </reportingOwner>

    <nonDerivativeTable>
        <nonDerivativeTransaction>
            <securityTitle>
                <value>Common Stock</value>
            </securityTitle>
            <transactionDate>
                <value>2015-11-18</value>
            </transactionDate>
            <transactionCoding>
                <transactionFormType>4</transactionFormType>
                <transactionCode>S</transactionCode>
                <equitySwapInvolved>0</equitySwapInvolved>
            </transactionCoding>
            <transactionAmounts>
                <transactionShares>
                    <value>10000</value>
                </transactionShares>
                <transactionPricePerShare>
                    <value>50.18</value>
                    <footnoteId id="F1"/>
                </transactionPricePerShare>
                <transactionAcquiredDisposedCode>
                    <value>D</value>
                </transactionAcquiredDisposedCode>
            </transactionAmounts>
            <postTransactionAmounts>
                <sharesOwnedFollowingTransaction>
                    <value>36562</value>
                </sharesOwnedFollowingTransaction>
            </postTransactionAmounts>
            <ownershipNature>
                <directOrIndirectOwnership>
                    <value>D</value>
                </directOrIndirectOwnership>
                <natureOfOwnership>
                    <value></value>
                </natureOfOwnership>
            </ownershipNature>
        </nonDerivativeTransaction>
    </nonDerivativeTable>

    <footnotes>
        <footnote id="F1">The price reported in Column 4 is a weighted average price. These shares were sold in multiple transactions at prices ranging from $50.00 to $50.58 inclusive. The reporting person undertakes to provide to Cambrex Corporation, any security holder of Cambrex Corporation, or the staff of the Securities and Exchange Commission, upon request, full information regarding the number of shares sold at each separate price within the range set forth in this Footnote 1 to this Form 4.</footnote>
    </footnotes>

    <remarks></remarks>

    <ownerSignature>
        <signatureName>Samantha Hanley for William B. Korb by POA</signatureName>
        <signatureDate>2015-11-20</signatureDate>
    </ownerSignature>
</ownershipDocument>`
```

http://play.golang.org/p/nJbAF0zKSJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `innerxml` tag on `DocumentType`, and give it the name of the element to to match (`xml:"documentType"`). From [the xml library docs](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Unmarshal):

> If the struct has a field of type `[]byte` or `string` with tag ",innerxml", `Unmarshal` accumulates the raw XML nested inside the element in that field. The rest of the rules still apply.

You don't need to store unprocessed XML. You're looking for the value of the field, so you don't need the tag.

[Working version](http://play.golang.org/p/FlhUIdsqr6)

*edit: For that matter, the `",innerxml"` tag will also break the `SchemaVersion` field as well—without a matching element (and since `SchemaVersion` is a string), it stores the whole document.

Answer (score 0):

```
I tried to do as much i could please suggest and help . 
I use this method please comment and suggest.  
https://play.golang.org/p/kb0HF8ykHW

  package main;
    import (
        "fmt"
        "encoding/xml"  
    )

    func main(){
    dxml := `
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <ownershipDocument>
        <schemaVersion>X0306</schemaVersion>
        <documentType>4</documentType>
        <periodOfReport>2015-11-18</periodOfReport>
        <issuer>
            <issuerCik>0000820081</issuerCik>
            <issuerName>CAMBREX CORP</issuerName>
            <issuerTradingSymbol>CBM</issuerTradingSymbol>
        </issuer>
        <reportingOwner>
            <reportingOwnerId>
                <rptOwnerCik>0001227832</rptOwnerCik>
                <rptOwnerName>KORB WILLIAM B</rptOwnerName>
            </reportingOwnerId>
            <reportingOwnerAddress>
                <rptOwnerStreet1>1 MEADOWLANDS PLAZA</rptOwnerStreet1>
                <rptOwnerStreet2/>
                <rptOwnerCity>EAST RUTHERFORD</rptOwnerCity>
                <rptOwnerState>NJ</rptOwnerState>
                <rptOwnerZipCode>07073</rptOwnerZipCode>
                <rptOwnerStateDescription/>
            </reportingOwnerAddress>
            <reportingOwnerRelationship>
                <isDirector>1</isDirector>
                <isOfficer>0</isOfficer>
                <isTenPercentOwner>0</isTenPercentOwner>
                <isOther>0</isOther>
            </reportingOwnerRelationship>
        </reportingOwner>
        <nonDerivativeTable>
            <nonDerivativeTransaction>
                <securityTitle>
                    <value>Common Stock</value>
                </securityTitle>
                <transactionDate>
                    <value>2015-11-18</value>
                </transactionDate>
                <transactionCoding>
                    <transactionFormType>4</transactionFormType>
                    <transactionCode>S</transactionCode>
                    <equitySwapInvolved>0</equitySwapInvolved>
                </transactionCoding>
                <transactionAmounts>
                    <transactionShares>
                        <value>10000</value>
                    </transactionShares>
                    <transactionPricePerShare>
                        <value>50.18</value>
                        <footnoteId id="F1"/>
                    </transactionPricePerShare>
                    <transactionAcquiredDisposedCode>
                        <value>D</value>
                    </transactionAcquiredDisposedCode>
                </transactionAmounts>
                <postTransactionAmounts>
                    <sharesOwnedFollowingTransaction>
                        <value>36562</value>
                    </sharesOwnedFollowingTransaction>
                </postTransactionAmounts>
                <ownershipNature>
                    <directOrIndirectOwnership>
                        <value>D</value>
                    </directOrIndirectOwnership>
                    <natureOfOwnership>
                        <value/>
                    </natureOfOwnership>
                </ownershipNature>
            </nonDerivativeTransaction>
        </nonDerivativeTable>
        <footnotes>
            <footnote id="F1">The price reported in Column 4 is a weighted average price. These shares were sold in multiple transactions at prices ranging from $50.00 to $50.58 inclusive. The reporting person undertakes to provide to Cambrex Corporation, any security holder of Cambrex Corporation, or the staff of the Securities and Exchange Commission, upon request, full information regarding the number of shares sold at each separate price within the range set forth in this Footnote 1 to this Form 4.</footnote>
        </footnotes>
        <remarks/>
        <ownerSignature>
            <signatureName>Samantha Hanley for William B. Korb by POA</signatureName>
            <signatureDate>2015-11-20</signatureDate>
        </ownerSignature>
    </ownershipDocument>

    `

        defer func() {
            if errD := recover(); errD != nil {
                    fmt.Println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!Panic Occured and Recovered in func main(), Error Info: ", errD)
                }
        }()

        var Owner Ownershipdocs 

        err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(dxml), &Owner)
            fmt.Println("xml.unmarshal error info :",err)
                fmt.Println("SchemaVersion : ",Owner.SchemaVersion)
                fmt.Println("DocumentType : ",Owner.DocumentType)
                fmt.Println("PeriodOfReport : ",Owner.PeriodOfReport)
                fmt.Println("IssuerCik : ",Owner.IssuerCik)
                fmt.Println("IssuerName : ",Owner.IssuerName)
                fmt.Println("IssuerTradingSymbol : ",Owner.IssuerTradingSymbol)
                fmt.Println("RptOwnerCik : ",Owner.RptOwnerCik)
                fmt.Println("RptOwnerName : ",Owner.RptOwnerName)
                fmt.Println("RptOwnerStreet1 : ",Owner.RptOwnerStreet1)
                fmt.Println("RptOwnerCity :  ",Owner.RptOwnerCity)
                fmt.Println("RptOwnerState : ",Owner.RptOwnerState)
                fmt.Println("RptOwnerZipCode : ",Owner.RptOwnerZipCode)
                fmt.Println("IsDirector : ",Owner.IsDirector)   
                fmt.Println("IsOfficer :  ",Owner.IsOfficer)

                fmt.Println("IsTenPercentOwner : ",Owner.IsTenPercentOwner)
                fmt.Println("IsOther : ",Owner.IsOther)
                fmt.Println("SecurityTitleValue : ",Owner.SecurityTitleValue)
                fmt.Println("TransactionDatevalue : ",Owner.TransactionDatevalue)
                fmt.Println("TransactionFormType : ",Owner.TransactionFormType)
                fmt.Println("TransactionCode : ",Owner.TransactionCode)
                fmt.Println("EquitySwapInvolved : ",Owner.EquitySwapInvolved)
                fmt.Println("TransactionSharesValue : ",Owner.TransactionSharesValue)
                fmt.Println("TransactionPricePerShareValue : ",Owner.TransactionPricePerShareValue)
                fmt.Println("TransactionPricePerSharefootnoteId :  ",Owner.TransactionPricePerSharefootnoteId)
                fmt.Println("TransactionAcquiredDisposedCodeValue : ",Owner.TransactionAcquiredDisposedCodeValue)

                fmt.Println("Footnote.Footnote : ",Owner.Footnote.Footnote)
                fmt.Println("OwnerSignaturesignatureName : ",Owner.OwnerSignaturesignatureName)
                fmt.Println("OwnerSignaturesignatureDate    : ",Owner.OwnerSignaturesignatureDate)  

    }

    type Ownershipdocs struct{
        SchemaVersion           string `xml:"schemaVersion"`
        DocumentType            string `xml:"documentType"`
        PeriodOfReport          string `xml:"periodOfReport"`
        IssuerCik               string `xml:"issuer>issuerCik"`
        IssuerName              string `xml:"issuer>issuerName"`
        IssuerTradingSymbol     string `xml:"issuer>issuerTradingSymbol"`
        RptOwnerCik             string `xml:"reportingOwner>reportingOwnerId>rptOwnerCik"`
        RptOwnerName            string `xml:"reportingOwner>reportingOwnerId>rptOwnerName"`

        RptOwnerStreet1         string `xml:"reportingOwner>reportingOwnerAddress>rptOwnerStreet1"`
        RptOwnerCity            string `xml:"reportingOwner>reportingOwnerAddress>rptOwnerCity"`
        RptOwnerState           string `xml:"reportingOwner>reportingOwnerAddress>rptOwnerState"`
        RptOwnerZipCode         string `xml:"reportingOwner>reportingOwnerAddress>rptOwnerZipCode"`

        IsDirector              string `xml:"reportingOwner>reportingOwnerRelationship>isDirector"`
        IsOfficer               string `xml:"reportingOwner>reportingOwnerRelationship>isOfficer"`  
        IsTenPercentOwner       string `xml:"reportingOwner>reportingOwnerRelationship>isTenPercentOwner"`
        IsOther                 string `xml:"reportingOwner>reportingOwnerRelationship>isOther"`        

        SecurityTitleValue      string `xml:"nonDerivativeTable>nonDerivativeTransaction>securityTitle>value"`
        TransactionDatevalue    string `xml:"nonDerivativeTable>nonDerivativeTransaction>transactionDate>value"`    
        TransactionFormType     string `xml:"nonDerivativeTable>nonDerivativeTransaction>transactionCoding>transactionFormType"`
        TransactionCode         string `xml:"nonDerivativeTable>nonDerivativeTransaction>transactionCoding>transactionCode"`
        EquitySwapInvolved      string `xml:"nonDerivativeTable>nonDerivativeTransaction>transactionCoding>equitySwapInvolved"`


        TransactionSharesValue                  string `xml:"nonDerivativeTable>nonDerivativeTransaction>transactionAmounts>transactionShares>value"`
        TransactionPricePerShareValue           string `xml:"nonDerivativeTable>nonDerivativeTransaction>transactionAmounts>transactionPricePerShare>value"`
        TransactionPricePerSharefootnoteId      string `xml:"nonDerivativeTable>nonDerivativeTransaction>transactionAmounts>transactionPricePerShare>footnoteId"`
        TransactionAcquiredDisposedCodeValue    string `xml:"nonDerivativeTable>nonDerivativeTransaction>transactionAmounts>transactionAcquiredDisposedCode>value"`

        SharesOwnedFollowingTransactionValue    string `xml:"nonDerivativeTable>nonDerivativeTransaction>ownershipNature>directOrIndirectOwnership>value"`

        Footnote                                Footnotes   `xml:"footnotes"`
        OwnerSignaturesignatureName             string       `xml:"ownerSignature>signatureName"`
        OwnerSignaturesignatureDate             string       `xml:"ownerSignature>signatureDate"`

    }

    type Footnotes struct{
        ID          string `xml:"id,attr"`
        Footnote    string `xml:"footnote"`

    }
```